# Get the background color of div - AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to get the background color of a DIV element when I click on that div.

HTML -

```
<div style="background-color:red" ng-click="getFilter($event)" class="agenda col-md-4">ABCDEGF/div>
```

JS Controller -

```
$scope.getFilter = function(event){

};
```

If we do in in jQuery, It would have been done as -

```
$('div').click(function(){
   $color = $(this).css('background-color');
});
```

But I want to do with angularJs. Someone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
$scope.getFilter = function(event) {
    $scope.color = $(event.currentTarget).css('background-color');
};
```

Comment: should use `event.currentTarget` since `target` can be a descendent element

Comment: @shaishabroy Its antipattern to have `jQuery` code in angular controller

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ng-style` for setting color dynamically, I'd just have it inside the API response for each record. I assumed that you are rendering all the elements using `ng-repeat` directive.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" 
   ng-style="{'background-color': item.color}"
   ng-click="getFilter(item);" 
   class="agenda col-md-4">
      ABCDEGF
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.getFilter = function(item){
    $color = item.color;
}
```

Comment: What if color applies dynamically ?

Comment: @sajalsuraj First tell me how you are going to pass dynamic color?

Comment: I have created Rest APIs for colors and I am accessing the color directly through PHP in a loop which creates so many DIVs dynamically with different background colors.

Comment: @sajalsuraj I mean to say from where you are getting color value? could you update your question with the same?

Comment: @sajalsuraj no..how are you rendering all rows? using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102009/discussion-between-sajalsuraj-and-pankaj-parkar).

Answer (score 1):

Created sample example with service to get and assign color dynamically. JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/q16fcq99/
Modify the service with your required call. Hope this will help.

```
    <body ng-app="SampleApp">
      <div ng-controller="fcController">
        <div ng-style="{'background-color': divColor}" ng-click="getFilter($event);" class="agenda col-md-4">
          ABCDEGF
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

        var sampleApp = angular.module("SampleApp", []);
    sampleApp.controller('fcController', function($scope, colorService) {
      $scope.divColor = 'red';
      $scope.getFilter = function(event) {
        $scope.divColor = colorService.getColor();
        console.log('Event Fired');
      };
    });
    sampleApp.service('colorService', function() {
      this.getColor = function() {
        return "blue"; //Call Actual Service to Get Color
      };
});
```